# Adding elements dynamically in String array but index 0 showing null?

Tags: java

I want to add some values in string array dynamically by using for loop.
when i debug the code at first for loop it is showing values which are adding.I want to check if any one of the string equals to my given value.but in for loop 2 at index 0 it showing null and at index 1 it showing the string value.

```
for(int i=0;i<someval;i++) {
  String[] mylist = new String[someval];
  mylist[i]=previousVal;
  System.out.println("Previous Value : " +mylist[i]);
}
for (int j = 0; j <=mylist.length; j++) { 
  if (mylist[j].equals(givenValue) ) {                  {
    System.out.println("your value found in the array");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are creating a **new** array using

```
mylist = new String...
```

during **each** loop iteration.

So, it doesn't really matter if you write something to an array, if the next step consists of throwing that array away.

In other words: make sure that you create the array just once; preferable before entering your loop.